# How to restrict user to access public folder through URL in angular application

Tags: angular, kubernetes

I have created a web application with the following folder structure:

- app
- assests
- main.ts
- index.html
- styles.scss
- styles

We have some configurational file inside assests directory. We want to restrict assests directory access from URL
**example:** **http:localhost:3000/assests/config.json**

We are following Microservices Architecture, Docker and Kubernetes.

Comment: Does the configuration file need to be deployed along with your application, or is it intended for use during the application's build process? If the latter, don't include it in your published application.

Comment: @DanielMann configuration file needs to be deployed along with application

Answer (score 0):

Everything in assets will be public. If it contains sensitive information, store it in a separate layer or module.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can’t directly restrict access to static files in the public folder through the URL because these files are served directly by the server, not through Angular. However, there are a few workarounds you can consider:

Server Configuration: Configure your server to restrict access to certain files or folders. For example, if you’re using an Apache server, you can use a .htaccess file to restrict access.

Move Sensitive Files: Move sensitive files out of the public directory and serve them through a server-side script. This script can check for authentication or other permissions before serving the file.

Angular Guards: While Angular guards can’t prevent access to static files, they can be used to protect routes and prevent unauthorized access to certain parts of your application.

Remember, security is a complex field and it’s important to understand the implications of any changes you make. Always test your application thoroughly to ensure that your security measures are working as expected

Comment: hello @varesh I have tried with .htaccess and angular gard. Both are not working.